# Add Google Sheet "Send" Button > Copies URL of Current Google Sheet, Sends to Email Address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry for the long title. Here is the scenario. I am creating several Google Sheet Templates. In order to launch, the end-user (In Google Drive) clicks on new, then the triangle next to spreadsheet, and then chooses "from Template" option. From the template dashboard they select the template. A new document based on the template is generated. Once the end-user fills out the information on the new document, I would like to have the end-user click a button that says something like "Submit to Accounting" or "Submit". The script associated to the button would do three things: 1) grab the url of the active sheet and 2) send it to an email address in a specific cell and 3) Display an on-screen success notification. (A bonus would be that the Submit button wouldn't be visible if you were to print said document, but that's just gettin fancy).

Comment: Sounds good. So what is your question?

Comment: All possible. Use a custom spreadsheet menu instead of a button and you'll achieve the not-printed result too.